# How to delete checked columns and send value of radio button?

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql

I wrote the code in PHP like this and I need to delete the rows from the database which "delete checkbox" in its delete column checked. And I want to send "verify" value (1 or 0) to the database. But I don't know SQL command to delete checked rows and I don't know how to get value of "verify" column (because it isn't possible to get the value using `$_POST[$id])`.

```
   <?php
    echo "<form action=\"index.php?go=save\" method=\"POST\">
        <table width=\"335\" border=\"1\">
        <tr>
        <th width=\"19\" scope=\"col\">ID</th>
        <th width=\"31\" scope=\"col\">Title</th>
        <th width=\"33\" scope=\"col\">URL</th>
        <th width=\"52\" scope=\"col\">Visitors</th>
        <th width=\"28\" scope=\"col\">Hits</th>
        <th width=\"52\" scope=\"col\">Verify</th>
        <th width=\"27\" scope=\"col\">Edit</th>
        <th width=\"41\" scope=\"col\">Delete</th>
      </tr>";
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY visitors DESC");
    while($write = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $id     = $write['id'];
        $title      = $write['title'];
        $url        = $write['url'];
        $visitors   = $write['visitors'];
        $hits       = $write['hits'];
    echo"   
      <tr>
        <td>$id</td>
        <td>$title</td>
        <td>$url</td>
        <td>$visitors</td>
        <td>$hits</td>
        <td>
        <input type=\"radio\" name=\"$id\"  value=\"1\" />Yes
        <input type=\"radio\" name=\"$id\"  value=\"0\" />No
        </td>
        <td><a href=\"index.php?go=edit\">Edit</a></td>
        <td>
          <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"$id\" />
      </td>
      </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>
        <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Save\"  />
        </form> ";
    ?>
```

Please, help me to solve this problem. If you know alternative variants, please write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete column:

```
<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"delete[]\" value=\"$id\" />
```

Checking and deleting:

```
foreach($_POST['delete'] as $id_to_delete) {
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM posts WHERE ID=".$id_to_delete)
}
```